# Camera rotation effect on pitch, yaw, roll

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm trying to calculate what the effective pitch, yaw, and roll are for an image.
I have the image's original pitch, yaw, and roll.  Then the image (camera) is rolled at some arbitrary angle.  I want to calculate the new relative pitch, yaw, and roll.

I know if pitch and yaw are 0, the new roll is just original roll + camera rotation angle. Likewise, if yaw and roll are 0, the new pitch is just the original pitch + camera rotation angle. For an arbitrary angle, I know both pitch and roll are affected. I imagine there is a simple equation for this, but I'm having trouble finding a reference.

Comment: you should check wikipedia for converting from Axis-angle to euler angle rotations.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestion to look up Euler angle rotations.  https://www.learnopencv.com/rotation-matrix-to-euler-angles/ is a good reference to answer this question.